# Hide worksheet in Excel Add-In from other VBA Projects

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Add-In which I am building which stores users settings in a `Settings` worksheet within the Add-In. I use the `Settings` sheet essentially as storage for boolean values and potentially, the user's registration details.

However, if I open up a new VBA Project and include the Add-In as a reference (In VBA: `Tools > References > MY Add-In`) then I can access the `Settings` worksheet and potentially break the password on it and hack the registration details.

The `Settings` sheet is set to be `xlVeryHidden` however it can be accessed via VBA code. Is there anyway to prevent this in Excel? In a module for example I can use the `Option Private Module` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you password protect and lock the project then your code and the worksheet objects can't be viewed. Go to Tools > VBAObject properties > Protection tab then tick 'Lock Project For Viewing' and then set a password in 'Password to view object properties'.

However, there is nothing to stop a hacker from...

```
For s = 1 to Sheets.Count
   Sheets(s).visible = True
Next s
```

...to see your Settings sheet.

There are a few options:

1) Have the settings sheet in a seperate workbook, or some other format like .txt and read from that (recommended).

2) Use some kind of encryption in your Setting sheet and decrypt it in your code, a really simple example is to use numbers in place of text so 'example' would = '5,24,1,13,16,12,5', but obviously you want to employ something more sophisticated that than and you can search online for many ways to do it.

3) Use 2, but store the decryption code somewhere else.

Be aware though, that for someone who knows what they're doing there really is no way to [prevent a VBA hack](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vba%20hack%20password), unless you use option 1/3 and have a way to store the file somewhere that isn't publicly accessible.