# Where to store user settings in a VBA Add-In?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building an Excel VBA Add-In which will require users to sign up and purchase a licence. They will then use that licence to activate the Add-In.

I'm not sure what the best way to store registration data (and general preferences for that matter) is? In the Registry or in a worksheet within the Add-In? Also, is there a way to store private information which cannot be manipulated by the user?

Answer (score 0):

As per your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325729/hide-worksheet-in-excel-add-in-from-other-vba-projects) a worksheet in the same book isn't safe. I'd assumed your other question refered to a local network, but from this question I'm guessing you'll be selling over the internet? In which case you should set up a database, perhaps MySql on your website and set up a table to store the [users IP](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vba%20get%20ip) and their unique licence key. You can then have your code [query the table](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vba%20mysql) and verify that IP has that licence. If your users are likely to use your file form various IP's then you'll need to expand on this a bit by gettng them to register their devices.

Comment: That's what I plan on doing yep. Sending a HTTP request from Excel is quite a large overhead. I need to think how I go about regularly checking they are still licenced to use the product without slowing Excel down too much.

Comment: Nah, just do it once at start, depending on your server it should take less than a couple of seconds, code some kind of waiting to verify message

Comment: How would you go about checking to make sure the user hasn't cancelled their subscription on a regular basis?

Comment: You're holding their subscription in your online database so just check it's still valid in the workbook open event via HTTP. An alternative method as you mentioned in your other post would be to set a registry value - not secure particularly - but if your customers need to buy an AddIn rather than code one themselves they're probably not capable of amending or even knowing about a registry key